# Enemies in a list: issue with colliding the enemies with the other enemies

Tags: c#, list, xna, collision-detection

I'm currently working on a game in which a list of enemies is spawned into the level randomly on the x-axis using a list up to the point of the maximum number to spawn (currently set at 10) I have a large portion of the game working however I currently have the problem that the enemies can overlap/stack on top of each other.

What I want is if the collision box of the enemy is intersecting another enemy in the list, for it to no overlap. (if that makes sense) this is the code I have for it so far.

```
        foreach (EnemyClass enemy1 in enemies)
        {
            if (enemy1.position.X < myPlayer.position.X - 10 && !enemy1.stopMoving)
            {
                enemy1.position.X += enemy1.amountToMove;                   
            }

            if (enemy1.position.X > myPlayer.position.X - 50 && !enemy1.stopMoving)
            {
                enemy1.position.X -= enemy1.amountToMove;
            }

            foreach (EnemyClass enemy2 in enemies)
            {
                if (enemy1 != enemy2 && enemy1.collisionBox.Intersects(enemy2.collisionBox))
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Collision Detected");
                }
            }

            enemy1.collisionX = (int)enemy1.position.X;
            enemy1.Update(graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: What I missed off was that they technically do collide, however they collide when they are 1000 pixels apart, when the sprite is actually 50 pixels wide.

EDIT: This is the changed collision code..

```
foreach (EnemyClass enemy in enemies)
        {
            enemy.collisionX = (int)enemy.position.X;

            if (enemy.position.X < myPlayer.position.X - 10 && !enemy.stopMoving)
            {
                enemy.position.X += enemy.amountToMove;                   
            }

            if (enemy.position.X > myPlayer.position.X - 50 && !enemy.stopMoving)
            {
                enemy.position.X -= enemy.amountToMove;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < enemies.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (enemies[i].collisionBox.Intersects(enemies[i].collisionBox))
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Collision Detected");
                    }
                }
            }

            enemy.Update(graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        }
```

EDIT: Here is the EnemyClass, which is where the collisionBox is contained:

```
public EnemyClass(Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition)
{
    texture = newTexture;
    position = newPosition;

    collisionBox = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, texture.Width, texture.Height);

    randX = random.Next(1, 3);
    speed = new Vector2(randX, 0);
}

public void Update(GraphicsDevice graphics)
{
    collisionBox = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, texture.Width, texture.Height);
}

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
}
```

Comment: I have removed tag(s) from your question's title based on  _[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)_ where the consensus is **no** _they should not_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the collision is being detected before all of the collision boxes have been updated.

My suggestions for how to order things:

1. Define the collision box in terms of position.X and position.Y so
   that it always accurately reflects the correct position.
2. Update all the enemies x- and y-positions.
3. Execute the snippet below *after* all the enemy positions have been updated.

```
foreach (EnemyClass enemy in enemies)
{
    if (enemy.position.X < myPlayer.position.X - 10 && !enemy.stopMoving)
    {
        enemy.position.X += enemy.amountToMove;                   
    }

    if (enemy.position.X > myPlayer.position.X - 50 && !enemy.stopMoving)
    {
        enemy.position.X -= enemy.amountToMove;
    }
    enemy.Update(graphics.GraphicsDevice);
} 

for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < enemies.Count; j++)
    {
        if (enemies[i].collisionBox.Intersects(enemies[j].collisionBox))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Collision Detected");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code also has an advantage in not detecting the same collision twice (i.e. enemy1/enemy2 and enemy2/enemy1).

Comment: I have changed my code according to what you suggested, however no matter how far away the second enemy is when it spawns, it outputs the console.write line to indicate collision.

Comment: Where is the x/y position located is relation to the sprite? Is it centered, or at the top-left, etc.? Also, you may have already realized, but the intersect method we want to use is `IntersectsWith` as opposed to `Intersect`. I've updated my example.

Comment: As far as I can tell, since I don't specify the centre of the sprite as the x/y, it is the top left (which is the case in general for my background etc.) - Sorry didn't see that you used IntersectsWith, is there a specific framework I'm missing in my code? I only have the option to use .Intersects not .IntersectsWith

Comment: No, it was my mistake. I was looking at the Rectangle used in System.Drawing, not in the XNA Framework. `Intersects` should be correct. As for your updated example, I think you want to do the collision check in a different loop as the position update. This is because enemies at the end of the list won't yet have the proper position when the collision check happens. I've again updated the example.

Comment: It's still generating the collision error whenever the second, third, etc. enemy spawns. I'm thinking this is because the collision box isn't being drawn correctly rather than the collision itself not working? Would it help if I posted the code where I first draw the collision box?

Comment: Yes, my hunch is that the collision box is not being updated.  It would be helpful to see the code for the collision box property/field. Specifically, are you saving a reference to the rectangle or returning a new one each time?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the EnemyClass, which is where my collisionBox is...I think I'm updating it wrong by defining a new Rectangle?

Comment: Ohmigosh, I made a terrible typo. I was comparing the collision box of enemies[i] to itself, instead of enemies[j]. The if-statement should be `if (enemies[i].collisionBox.Intersects(enemies[j].collisionBox))`. No wonder it was always returning true. See update. You're doing the correct thing by creating a new Rectangle.

Comment: Ahh yeah no worries haha! Yes that seems to have somewhat fixed the problem! The collision box still seems rather large (probably to do with the size I've set it too!) but it doesn't instantly detect collision until it is somewhat close. Thanks very much for your help, think I'll be able to sort the rest out from here :)